# What is an unsatisfied man called?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

What is a person who has achieved many things but he thinks that he has achieved a little but needs to achieve a lot more called?

He is neither depressed nor ambitious.I would like  to  have  the answer in the  form  of  a  noun.

> **Mr  Sham  is hailed  as  a great success in life .But  he  thinks he  has  achieved a  little. He  is   a/an------------------**

I would  like  to  a  know the  word  which  fits in  the  blank.

Comment: "He felt increasingly **dissatisfied** with his life as he approached middle age." https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dissatisfied

Comment: @Kris  It  is just  a  definition. I want  a  word  in  the form  of  a  noun. It  need  not  have  been  down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Discontent*** should be the word you are looking for -

## Discontent

> noun
>
> **b**: restless aspiration for improvement

**OR**

You could use ***insatiable*** too -

> [**insatiable**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/insatiable): always wanting more and never feeling satisfied

---

The count noun is '***[malcontent](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/malcontent)***', which has a human referent. But is rare. And doesn't have the required meaning. – Edwin Ashworth

Comment: +1 for insatiable

Comment: Insatiable is an  adjective.I  think  discontent  is the  proper  word in the  context.

Comment: -1 for insatiable.

Comment: @Justin — Insatiable means “can never be satisfied”. You may deduce that from your knowledge of human nature, but it is not part of the description of the word.

Comment: The use of *discontent* as a ***noun*** here is wrong. If you are describing somebody's nature, then you are using the ***adjective*** of the word. The noun sense of *discontent* would be *now is the winter of our discontent* or (correct but very awkward) *he is a discontent*, but that sense would be completely inappropriate to this question.

Comment: The count noun is 'malcontent', which has a human referent. But is rare. And doesn't have the required meaning.